# using props in computed (vue)

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, vue-props

I have this simple 2 component vue app : (nuxt, composition api and ts)

Parent :

```js
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="txt">
    <Child :txt="txt"></Child>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
let txt = ref("")
</script>
```

Child :

```js
<template>
    <p>{{ txt }}</p>
    <p>{{ txt + " 1" }}</p>
    <p>{{ txtComputed }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const { txt } = defineProps<{
    txt: string
}>()

let txtComputed = computed(() => {
    return txt + " 1"
})
</script>
```

I would like the txtComputed to change according to the txt. But it's stuck at the first value (just `" 1"`)

If I have more complex logic than just adding 1, I'd like to not code it in the html.

So why is the computed not working with props ?

Comment: please share the package.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned object from `defineProps` is a reactive object, similar to ones created with [reactive()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive). When you destructure it, you bind the current values to variables - those values will not be reactive anymore.

As the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure) states:

> you need to always access props as `props.x` in order to retain reactivity. This means you cannot destructure `defineProps` because the resulting destructured variables are not reactive and will not update.

So if you want to preserve reactivity, you have to assign the result from defineProps directly:

```
const props = defineProps<...>()
const txtComputed = computed(() => props.txt + " 1")
```

Alternatively, you can turn individual props into refs with [`toRef()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref) or all at once with [`toRefs()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much clearer now ^^